# How to add one more icon using fontello without downloading a new group package

Tags: css, svg, font-face, icon-fonts

I use fontello for some icons on my website. When you download from fontello they deliver:

- .ttf
- .woff
- .svg
- .eot
- css file with @font face to link all together

Everything works fine with this but I always find myself with this issue which I would like if somebody could give me a hint:

**-What if I want to add a new icon into this set after downloading?**

There are a lot of icons and searching for all again can bring errors. I would like to know if there is a simple method of downloading the extra icon and adding it to the set that you have already.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There actually is a built-in "Import" function which allows you to import your current set of icons and modify it:

[image: Fontello.com import zip archive or SVG]

Comment: Therefore you could import the download given by fontello and after you can insert new icons and download it again. This way all the class names will be intact? Nice, this really seems helpful

Comment: that's right, if you take a look at your config.json file you'll see that each icon has its own ID besides the CSS class. Fontello sets up for you default class names but you can always customize them using the "Customize names" option

Comment: Important: You need to mark your imported icons as well (using the mouse) and add the ones you need. Then click "Download webfont (x)"

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Gift Of Speed](https://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/) website to convert a `font-file` into `base-64`.

Good luck...